# removing last char doesn't work in loop's first run after concatenation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to add or remove indents to show data in more readable way, but after each concatenation first try of removing the last `char` from string doesn't work. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong but I can't see what.

```
array = [['1.1', 'val 1.1'], ['1.2', 'val 1.2', [['1.2.1', 'val 1.2.1', [['1.2.1.1', 'val 1.2.1.1'], ['1.2.1.2', 'val 1.2.1.2', [['1.2.1.2.1', 'val 1.2.1.2.1'], ['1.2.1.2.2', 'val 1.2.1.2.2']]], ['1.2.1.3', 'val 1.2.1.3']]], ['1.2.2', 'val 1.2.2'], ['1.2.3', 'val 1.2.3']]], ['1.3', 'val 1.3']]

def pr_lo(array, indent):
    for el in array:
        print(indent, " ", el[0], ": ", el[1])
        if len(el) == 3:
            indent = indent + "-"
            pr_lo(el[2], indent)
    indent = indent[:-1]

pr_lo(array, "")
```

The output always looks the same:

```
   1.1 :  val 1.1
   1.2 :  val 1.2
-    1.2.1 :  val 1.2.1
--    1.2.1.1 :  val 1.2.1.1
--    1.2.1.2 :  val 1.2.1.2
---    1.2.1.2.1 :  val 1.2.1.2.1
---    1.2.1.2.2 :  val 1.2.1.2.2
---    1.2.1.3 :  val 1.2.1.3
--    1.2.2 :  val 1.2.2
--    1.2.3 :  val 1.2.3
-    1.3 :  val 1.3
```

`1.1`, `1.2` and `1.3` should be in the same line but they somehow can't be.

Comment: When calling a function recursively, local variables are always newly created on function start and destroyed at the end. This means that each invocation of `pr_lo` has its own `indent` which is set independently (of course the content can be transferred as parameter in a function call as initial setting, but the variable can be changed independently).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need to worry about taking away the indent by not having to worry about setting index with the following method:

```
def pr_lo(array, indent):
    for el in array:
        print(indent, " ", el[0], ": ", el[1])
        if len(el) == 3:
            pr_lo(el[2], indent + '-')
pr_lo(array, "")
```

Comment: That thing worked. I don't know how I could miss that. Just one more indent. Anyway, thanks for help.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You not only made this work, You even improved this. You saved me probably more than hour of looking into code without any idea what's happening